# TightVNC Server sometimes fail to start on RHEL7.4

Tags: systemd, pam, vnc, rhel7

I've a RHEL 7.4 box with TightVNC service enabled on boot and sometimes the service fails to start with a PAM permission denied error:

```
systemd[2027]: pam_nologin(login:account): conversation failed
systemd[2027]: Failed at step PAM spawning /usr/bin/vncserver: Operation not permitted
systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: control process exited, code=exited status=224
systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service failed.
```

But after boot if I simply restart the service it starts successfully.

I'm not sure what's causing this issue, or if it's a precedence issue during systemd startup on boot.

The service file was created this way:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=vncuser
PAMName=login

# Clean any existing files in /tmp/.X11-unix environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1280x1024 -nolisten tcp
PIDFile=/home/vncuser/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

RHEL 7.4 is fully updated until it was possible, since the subscription does not offer EUS.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you freeze on 7.4, then? 7.6 is current and supported.

Comment: Requirement for ANSYS Engineering software support.

Comment: They require exactly 7.4? That's a little odd.

Comment: Yep, take a look at the table on page 3 of this PDF: https://www.ansys.com/-/media/ansys/corporate/files/pdf/solutions/it-professionals/platform-support/platform-support-strategy-plans-192.pdf?la=en; the last release available of ANSYS as today is 19.2.

Comment: Well, you have a couple of options if you want updates: You can buy EUS, or you can just update to 7.6. My experience tells me that you're unlikely to have any sort of problem with updating to 7.6; why they don't list "support" for it iis a complete mystery. Perhaps they just never tested that version of their product on 7.6. It might be worth trying it out in a lab to see what happens.